# Objective-C restricting physics body so that it does not fall over

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

My issue is that I have my main character which is an SKNode and I have applied a physics body to it but I dont want the node to freely rotate and fall over when it reacts to the scene ( e.g if the character hits the side of a block it will fall over ) but I want the node to stay upright no matter what happens to it yet still having the gravity applied to it like a normal physics body . If any body could help me with the programming of this , this is the code I have so far ( does not have an attempt of restricting the physics body ) :

```
character.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:character.size];
```

Thanks for the Help !!

Comment: see class reference: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsBody_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKPhysicsBody/allowsRotation

Comment: I don't know much about SpriteKit but is there something like a weight or gravity for an element? If you set the weight high enough I suppose it will just stand there and not be affected by anything.